Wiggle bones adddon not installing in blender 4.3
I am trying to install the wiggle bones addon in my blender, but it's not showing up. It is on my appdata folder, it's also in the addons core folder from my instalation,it just does not show up in the preferences whatsoever



I suspect you downloaded it from the Github Repository here:
shteeve3d/blender-wiggle-2: Rewrite of blender-wiggle with new features and physics
But you downloaded the repository itself, instead of the release on the release page (accessible from the right-sidebar on the repository main page):
Releases · shteeve3d/blender-wiggle-2
The issue with downloading the repository itself is that:

It works only if the addon has an __init__.py file in the top-level folder of the repository, which isn't the case here
You probably download extra files that aren't meant to be shipped with the addon, like the readme, licence, github files, development files, promotion material and whatever else.
The files in the repo are not necessarily meant to be used as is, when there's a dedicated release download somewhere else. The repository is really "whatever the developer is at right now", it could literally be a non-functional WIP.

In this specific case, the developer ships an actual release consisting of a single wiggle_2.py file which can be installed from Blender's GUI or placed in the scripts/addons directory, not in a subfolder.

Hello @Lauloque, so if you put wiggle_2.py in the scripts/addons folder, how do you activate it afterwards? I can't make it work...

If it is the correct file, then in Blender you can use the top-right popover menu in the addons list to refresh the list, or even restart Blender, and then it should appear in the list.
